# JS problem - Rock, paper, scissors game only returning ties and losses no wins

Tags: javascript

This is my first time asking a question here. So, my main issue I'm having is that when I play my game of rock, paper, scissors I only ever tie or lose a round - I never win. I've tested this out in multiple browsers and on codepen and the result is similar. I have absolutely no idea what is the problem with my code. Could someone point me in the right direction or point out any glaring mistakes in my js code? Thank you!

```
// declares that default score of both players is set to zero at begining of each game
let playerScore = 0
let computerScore = 0
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input')

// this function randomly returns either rock, paper, or scissors
function computerPlay() {
  let choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
  return choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)]
}

// disables multiple buttons when one is clicked  
function disableButtons() {
  buttons.forEach(elem => {
      elem.disabled = true
  })
}

// main function for game
function playRound(playerSelection) {
  let computerSelection = computerPlay()
  let result = ""

  if ((playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'scissors') ||
      (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'paper') ||
      (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'rock')) {
      
      playerScore += 1
      result = ('You win! ' + playerSelection + ' beats ' + computerSelection
          + '<br><br>Player score: ' + playerScore + '<br>Computer score: ' + computerScore)

      if (playerScore == 5) {
          result += '<br><br>You won the game! Reload the page to play again.'
          disableButtons()
      }
  }
  else if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
      result = ('It\'s a tie... You both chose ' + playerSelection
          + '<br><br>Player score: ' + playerScore + '<br>Computer score: ' + computerScore)
  }
  else {
      computerScore += 1
      result = ('You lose. ' + computerSelection + ' beats ' + playerSelection + '.' 
          + '<br><br>Player score: ' + playerScore + '<br>Computer score: ' + computerScore)

      if (computerScore == 5) {
          result += '<br><br>Computer won the game! Reload the page to play again.'
          disableButtons()
      }
  }
    
// prints result to html file
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result
    return
}

// adds the functionality to initiate a round of the game when a button is clicked 
buttons.forEach(button =>{
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        playRound(button.value)
    })
})
```

Comment: This is a great opportunity to begin familiarizing yourself with a debugger.  For in-browser JavaScript code, browsers come with debugging tools already available.  With a debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes, observing the exact runtime behavior and changing values of the variables.  When you do this, which operation in your code first produces and unexpected result?  What were the values used at the time?  What was the result?  What was expected?  Why?

Comment: What is `button.value`? Please show the relevant HTML, but also use your browser’s debugger to stop on one of the relevant lines (click in the margin of the `if ((playerSelection == …` line to set a breakpoint) and see what the value of `playerSelection` is. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Set_a_breakpoint

Comment: I would review it, elements in choices array are all capital letter whilst the comparison of computerSelection and playerSelection are to all lower case strings.

Comment: yes, this is a typo. You will want to be consistent, I would recommend just making them all lower case everywhere or converting them to lower case with toLowerCase before your compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choices of the computer are (`computerSelection`):

```
  let choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
```

But in your comparison condition:

```
 if ((playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'scissors') ||
      (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'paper') ||
      (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'rock')) {
```

And the comparison will always return false,
as you use lowercase values instead of capital first character.

> Rock != rock
>
> Scissors != scissors
>
> Paper != paper

As commented above, it also depends on the value you get from the buttons (aka `playerSelection`).
Be consistent with the lowercase/uppercase of the choices and I think it should work.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you. So if I wanted to make this case insensitive would that also solve my problem? If so, how would I go about implementing that?

Comment: A better option would be to consistent with the values. Just uppercase the first characters of the options all over your code/application. Another option (less recommended) is to use the .toLowerCase method - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase